# WP_query no matches on multiple values in array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

At the moment I’m breaking my head on a WP_query that doesn’t give me the correct results.

What I am trying to do is make a result based on values stored in an array.

Please see the code below;

```
// Array contents:

// $size_array = Array
// (
//   [0] => 7
//   [1] => 4
//   [2] => 2
//  )

// $color_array : 
// Array
// (
//   [0] => red
//   [1] => blue
//   [2] => orange
// )

    $args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'rondreizen',
    'meta_query'    => array(   
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => ‘size’,
            'value'     => $size_array,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => ‘color’,
            'value'     => $color_array,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
); 

$shoes = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $shoes->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {

}
```

---

I am trying to get a result that both matches 1 or more of the values. So for example: a shoe in size 4 and in color orange .

At the moment, I only get a result when I have only 1 item in the Arrays. I also tried to us the 'IN' compare method. But that didn't gave me any results either.

I tried to describe the issue as clear as possible. Hope anyone can help me out. :-)

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Anyone have a solution? I am still trying to get it to work. Unfortunately no result yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'rondreizen',
    'meta_query'    => array(   
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => ‘size’,
            'value'     => $size_array
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => ‘color’,
            'operator'  => IN,
            'value'     => $color_array
        )
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
); 

$shoes = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $shoes->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. - I tried the 'operator' => IN option. But it doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Please check this out as I debug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664245/dynamic-meta-query

Comment: I have been looking into the solution given here: [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183182/meta-query-compare-in-not-working) - however, I am planning on making a couple of arrays to find relative 'posts' based on multiple values. That would create a crazy long query. Maybe I have to look into a regular mysql solution.. But WP_Query would be much better.